# Find the Laurent Series expansion for $\displaystyle{f(z) = ze^{1/(z-1)}}$ valid for $\left|z-1\right|> 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, laurent-series

Can you help me and discuss me on the question?

Expand $\displaystyle{f(z) = ze^{1/(z-1)}}$ in a Laurent series valid for $\displaystyle{\left|z-1\right|> 0}$.

I have no idea anything about the exponential complex form to fnd the Laurent series for that.  I know that the laurent series of $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ for every complex $z$.  Can I just substitiute it?

Comment: Check when $e^z$ converges ($|z|<\infty$) and substitute it, and see it really works.

Comment: e^z converges because complex exponentials are differentiable. So what is next?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$e^{w}=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{w^{k}}{k!},\,\left|w\right|<+\infty$$ we have, taking $w=\frac{1}{z-1}$, that for $0<\left|z-1\right|<+\infty$ (these bounds follow from $\left|w\right|=\left|\frac{1}{z-1}\right|<+\infty$) we obtain

\begin{align} 
ze^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{z}{k!\left(z-1\right)^{k}} & =\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{k!\left(z-1\right)^{k-1}}+\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{k!\left(z-1\right)^{k}}
\\ & =z-1+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k!\left(z-1\right)^{k-1}}+\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{k!\left(z-1\right)^{k}} 
\\ & =z-1+\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)!\left(z-1\right)^{k}}+\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{k!\left(z-1\right)^{k}}
\\ & =z-1+\sum_{k\geq0}\left(\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)!}+\frac{1}{k!}\right)\frac{1}{\left(z-1\right)^{k}}
\\ &= \color{red}{z-1+\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{k+2}{\left(k+1\right)!}\frac{1}{\left(z-1\right)^{k}}}.
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) but this can be simplified a small bit: $(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I am an idiot :D thank you

Comment: Thank you so much all.

Comment: @ArianaTibor You're welcome. I recall to you that, if you think that my answer solves your problem, you can accept it.

Comment: Hi, I'm still confuse and can't figure out how we arrive the expression in red from the previous one. Sorry

Comment: @ArianaTibor I added some passages, let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: You are so kind. Thanks.  I just cannot see the picture behind why is $\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{z}{k!(z-1)^k} =  \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!(z-1)^{k-1}} + \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{k!(z-1)^k} $.  Where does $z$ go? I tried simplifying both sides but I really can't see why there are two terms of summation on the right. Sorry my bad

Comment: @ArianaTibor The trick in that passage is to write $z=z-1+1$ and then divide the fraction in $\frac{z-1}{\textrm{things}}+\frac{1}{\textrm{things}}$. All of that because we want to write the Laurent series in $z=1$, so we must have powers of $z-1$. However, don't bother asking more questions: that's the purpose of this site, so ask anything that doesn't come back to you ;)

Comment: Hi, @MarcoCantarini.  Sorry if I was not able to reply you immediately, it was already midnight when I finally able to figured it out.  Thanks for being patient explaning.  I got it from here already. #lovelots